# TestNG - How can I set up the order of running @Test methods through testng.xml?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, testng

I have a 30 `@Test` methods and 2 *Java* methods in my `@Test` class.
I need to run these 2 *Java* methods after concrete `@Test` method,for example,
`TestMethod5()`.
How can I do that ?

For instance:

```
@Test
public void TestMethod5() {

/* compiled code */

}

public void Method1(){/* compiled code */};
public void Method2{/* compiled code */};
```

Need 2 methods:

> 1) with testng.xml
>   2) with Intellij IDEA
>
> Note: `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` works only with **extends
>   classname** command. These 2 Java methods check the rendering of
>   buttons&labels with `assertTrue()` method so I don`t want to mess my
>   base class with them.

---

Yeah,these methods are part of test(and future similar tests too),but I can`t just copy the content of them and paste in each method I want...Then @Test methods will be messed(large code).I just need to check the rendering of labels and butons in these methods:

```
 public void method1_ButtonsTest() {

  assertTrue1();
  assertTrue2();

 }


 public void method2_LabelsTest() {

  assertTrue3();
  assertTrue4();
 }


@Test
public void Test1();

@Test
public void Test2();

@Test
public void Test3();

@Test
public void Test4();

@Test
public void Test5();

@Test
public void Test6();


@Test
public void Test7();

@Test
public void Test8();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just call those methods?

```
@Test public void testMethod5() {
    ...
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

Comment: I agree, if these methods are higher-level assertions, then they're part of the test, just as simpler assertXxxx are.

Comment: Yeah,these methods are part of test(and future similar tests too),but I can`t just copy the content of them and paste in each method I want...Then @Test methods will be messed(large code).I just need to check the rendering of labels and butons in these methods     public void method1() {

Comment: I'm not saying you should copy their content, just that they are higher-level assertions, and therefore should be called explicitely from each test which needs these assertions. They could be called ```assertLabelRendering()``` and ```assertButtonRendering()```.

Comment: Besides, if they're not called in the test itself but in an ```@AfterMethod``` or equivalent, if they fail, you probably won't know directly which test has failed, only that the external assertions have failed in an independent method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the base class and also don't want to call the methods directly in the test then you could add another @AfterMethod to the test class and only run the methods for the test cases you call out, then call the @AfterMethod in the base class, something like this:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void postTestCase(ITestResult _result) {
    if (_result.getMethod().getMethodName().equals("Test1")){
          System.out.println("Do something here...");
    }
    //Call the @AfterMethod in the base class
    super.postTestCase(_result);
}
```